# empty HTML-file with vertical scrollbar in safari mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari, scrollbar

First I've got a fullscreen landing page and (only !!) in safari mobile in landscape-mode appears a vertical scrollbar.

I wonder why, so I began to delete elements and styles peu à peu. In the end I had a 'empty' file like this:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
</head>
```

Even in this file the scrollbar appears. Are there any tricks to ban this bugging phenomenon?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: o.O in my file and developer tool exists a body-tag

Comment: @fheck Look at the URL you gave me - its a blank page.

Comment: Yes, I know. And even on this page appears a vertical scrollbar in safari mobile (landscape mode / iPad). That's the problem!

On f-heck.de (not a blank page) you'll see the same effect/bug. The content is definitively not as high as the viewport..